# Как взять текст из класса DIV у которого есть атрибут #text

Tags: python, html, парсер, selenium

Вот мой код:

```
a = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "bbWrapper")
for elem in a:
 aas = a[0].get_attribute('#text')
```

но при поиске он получает None
Вот сам HTML код

```
    <div class="bbWrapper"><b>Ваш игровой ник и CID персонажа:</b> Benkaca Aux 52IX<br>
<br>
<b>Статический ID(SID) нарушителя:</b> 2UIT 41XT<br>
<br>
<b>Описание ситуации:</b> SK, DM<br>
<br>
<b>Дата и время нарушения:</b> 27 Авг 2022<br>
<br>
<b>Доказательство: <div class="bbMediaWrapper">
    <div class="bbMediaWrapper-inner">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-PjEPthv1A4?wmode=opaque&amp;start=0" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
    </div>
</div></b></div>
```

Comment: Я хочу наример получить Benkaca Aux 52IX как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите именно этот текст: "Benkaca Aux 52IX", то можно сделать вот так:

```
a = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "bbWrapper")
for elem in a:
    aas = elem.text.splitlines()[0].split(":")[1].strip()
    print(aas)
```

Результат: 
Benkaca Aux 52IX

Если выполнить поиск по тегу "b", то теги он найдет, а вот то, что за ними будет отброшено.

Или можно еще так, если вы хотите найти каждый элемент, который стоит за тегом "b":

```
a = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "bbWrapper")
for elem in a:
    for aa in elem.text.splitlines():
        if aa.strip() != "":
            if aa.split(":")[1].strip():
                print(aa.split(":")[1].strip())
```

В этом случае результат будет:

Benkaca Aux 52IX
2UIT 41XT
SK, DM
27 Авг 2022

И если заменить индекс элемента с "1" на "0", то получите то, что в тегах "b".

Результат:

Ваш игровой ник и CID персонажа
Статический ID(SID) нарушителя
Описание ситуации
Дата и время нарушения
Доказательство